# Probability problem - Joint Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In order to become approved, a device has to pass two stages of tests.

In the first stage, there are two independent tests. The probability of passing the first one, is 0.6. The probability of passing the second one is 0.8. In order to pass the first stage, the device must pass at least one of the two tests.

In the second stage, there is only one test. Only devices that pass the first stage reach the second stage. The probability that a device will get to the second stage and pass it, is 0.7. The probability that a device will pass all 3 tests is 0.28.

We will define the random variable X to be the number of tests that a device will pass in the first stage. The random variable Y will get a value of 1 if a device was approved and 0 if not.

What is the joint probability distribution of X and Y ?
Are X and Y independent ? Are they correlated ?

My problem here is mainly in determining the probability of passing the second test.

Let's define: A - passing the first test, B - passing the second test, C - passing the third test

The probability of passing at least of of the first tests in the first stage is:

$P(A\cup B)=0.6+0.8-0.6\cdot 0.8=0.92$

I thought to continue with:

$0.92\cdot x=0.7$

Resulting with:

$P(C)=0.76$

But I got a feeling it is wrong. In addition, where does the 0.28 comes in ?

Edit: The number I have calculated must be wrong as I have continued with it and got an unreasonable probability of over 1 somewhere.

Comment: On its face, the system looks overdetermined.  You have two ways to compute the probability of passing the second stage (conditioned on reaching it) and it isn't obvious that they give the same value.  I'd start by computing it both ways and checking that.

Comment: Your calculation of $P(A \cup B)$ assumes independence, which may not be justified.  In particular $0..6\times 0.8 \times 0.7= 0.336$ not $0.28$

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are clearly not independent as $X=0 \iff Y=0$

Comment: The first two tests ARE independent. The third one may not be

Answer (score 0):

Let's define an additional variable $Z = X - C$, denoting the number of tests during the first stage that are passed.

For the multivariate distribution, we'll want to compute the following quantities:

- $P(X=0, Y=0) = P(X=0) = P(Z=0)$, because the device never passes if less than two tests pass and because $Z=0$ implies $C=0$ (if the product doesn't pass the first stage, it will not enter the second stage)
- $P(X=1, Y=0) = P(X=1) = P(Z=1, C=0)$
- $P(X=2, Y=0) = P(Z=2, C=0)$, because if $Z=1$ and $C=1$, then $Y=1$
- $P(X=3, Y=0) = 0$, because if all tests are passed, then $Y=1$
- $P(X=0, Y=1) = 0$
- $P(X=1, Y=1) = 0$
- $P(X=2, Y=1) = P(Z=1, C=1)$
- $P(X=3, Y=1) = P(X=3) = 0.28$, as per the information in the problem.

Next, we'll note that $P(Z = 0) = 0.2\cdot 0.4 = 0.08$, $P(Z = 2) = 0.8\cdot 0.6 = 0.48$ and $P(Z = 1) = 1 - P(Z=0) - P(Z=2) = 0.44$.

Then, it follows from Bayes' rule and the information in the problem that \begin{align}
0.7 &= P(Z > 0, C=1)\\
&= P(Z=1, C=1) + P(Z=2, C=1) \\
&= P(C=1|Z=1)\cdot P(Z=1) + P(Z=2, C=1)\\
&= P(C=1|Z=1)\cdot 0.44 + 0.28,
\end{align}
hence $P(C=1, Z=1) = 0.42$ and $P(C=1|Z=1) = \frac{0.42}{0.44}$. Additionally,
\begin{align}
P(C=0, Z=1) &= P(C=0|Z=1)\cdot P(Z=1) \\
&= (1 - P(C=1|Z=1))\cdot P(Z=1) \\
&= \frac{0.02}{0.44}\cdot 0.44 = 0.02
\end{align}.

The final missing quantitiy is the probability $P(Z=2, C=0)$, but that can be computed using the fact that the multivariate distribution needs to sum to 1.

Combining everything, we get

- $P(X=0, Y=0) = 0.08$
- $P(X=1, Y=0) = 0.02$
- $P(X=2, Y=0) = 0.2$
- $P(X=3, Y=0) = 0$
- $P(X=0, Y=1) = 0$
- $P(X=1, Y=1) = 0$
- $P(X=2, Y=1) = 0.42$
- $P(X=3, Y=1) = 0.28$.

Comment: Thank you. X is the number of tests the device will pass in the FIRST stage. Therefore it cannot be 3.